# Link-only or not?

Tags: discussion

I came across a couple low-quality posts,

[The first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832835/how-lock-a-file-in-windows-using-c),

> Just going off of the subject line, I found a _lock_file() API in the CRT:
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/lock-file

[The second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48222391/is-it-possible-to-display-preferences-inside-the-app-with-settings-bundle),

> Check out [InAppSettingsKit](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit). This library mimics the behaviour of the Settings app in a View Controller that you can display in your app.

and [the third one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35800068/how-can-i-generate-javascript-api-documentation-for-github-pages),

> Though I haven't updated it in a while, https://github.com/punkave/dox-foundation is another option. It will just generate HTML files that you could commit to your `gh-pages` branch.

They are all short, but they generally provide enough information to the OP, and frankly I don't think having code samples or elaborate description will be especially helpful. What do you guys think?

However, they still got more deletions than "looks okay"s.

Comment: When evaluating link-only just ask yourself, if the link was dead would it still answer the question? Usually the answer is no and the simple fix is to include some code or example from the link in the answer.

Comment: They are link only. They should be deleted, IMO. Only the first one _might_ be an answer.

Comment: The second and the third one aren't link only (but bad nonetheless) and I can't judge the first example since I don't know how clear "_lock_file() API in the CRT" is for someone who knows the context.

Comment: @Tom How are the second and third **not** link only?

Comment: @yivi They mention the lib names and that's fine (according to the NAA link-only rules). You can find these libs without a link by searching for them.

Comment: @Tom By that logic, almost **all** link only answers are actually not link only, since using whatever text the link has you can always find whatever external resource has been linked (_praised be the google_).

Comment: I thought the crux of the matter was that the actual answer had to exist in SO, not actually **be** an external resource on itself, without description on how it should be used and applies to the question at hand.

Comment: @yivi Having a text like "looks what I found" referring to blog is obviously a big difference to a clear lib name paired with a link where to get that lib. That lib might still be accessible from other sites, but you would need sites likes archive.org to get a version from the linked blog page. Not all "text+link" combinations are equal. Both answers name a lib and if that's what OP asked for, then their are valid answer. (Reminder: that a question asks for off-site resources are a different issue and we're not talking about the quality of the answer, only if they are link-only or not).

Comment: @yivi it's not so much about being able to find a source page, it's about having a keyword which can be used for further research. A library name is such a keyword. That turns the answer from being link-only into being low quality and definitely worth a downvote and a thousand personal wishes to be able to flag it VLQ (but you can't).

Comment: Required reading on MSE: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370)

Comment: @AshleyMedway _"the simple fix is to include some code or example from the link in the answer"_, that is plagiary, especially if it becomes the main part of the answer. You can't copy things without permission of the copyright owner. Quoting might be okay under some situations, but simply copying things from external sites is not the way to go.

Comment: Reducing time spent searching is one of the *exact* reasons the Exchange sites are so popular.  Deciding that we are not going to help people search is ridiculous.  Of course people need to at least try their own search first, but have you noticed that the Exchange sites frequently come up first?  Often people need hints where to look for solutions that we have already researched - a "look here" response (with a bit of description why it fits) can indeed be a valid answer.  Don't get caught up with the hubristic idea that the Exchanges MUST BE the last stop of the users quest.

Answer (score 26):

The test is: **Is it still a valid answer when the link is removed?**

Let's see:

> Just going off of the subject line, I found a `_lock_file()` API in the CRT (C runtime library).

Yup, it cites a potential solution, the details of which I can search for on my own.

> Check out InAppSettingsKit. This library mimics the behaviour of the Settings app in a View Controller that you can display in your app.

Ditto.

> Though I haven't updated it in a while, dox-foundation is another option. It will just generate HTML files that you could commit to your `gh-pages` branch.

Ditto.

None of these are particularly *good* answers.

But to me, there's no question that **all three clear the bar of what is considered a minimal viable answer** on Stack Overflow (if only barely, especially in the first case).

Flagging as not-an-answer or voting to delete as link-only-answer is **not the appropriate action**. If you consider an answer not useful, then downvoting is the thing to do.

Comment: Agree, I don't see how recommending a library is a link only answer, adding the link adds a bit of value.  However I don't think they are good answers in that they don't actually explain much or give sample code.  Asking for a library is considered a bad question but providing one is a good answer.

Comment: @Tom Yup, thanks, fixed!

Comment: "None of these are particularly good answers." I bet you that the questions are the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If the answer is useless without the link, then it is a link-only answer. Simple as that. All answers should be useful on their own. You can provide a link as a reference, or even as a "read more here", but the answer should answer the question without the link.

There are questions that cannot be answered without a link, such as "where can I find a lib that does X?" but these questions are also considered OT.

An important reason is that a link may die. Then the answer is suddenly completely useless.

I would vote to close all of your examples.

Comment: Correction: if an answer is useless without the link _markup_ then it should be deleted. The text from the link still counts as text. All of the examples in the question are actually appropriate.